# Temporarily replacing an image at a random, constantly shifting position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Building on my previous inquiries, I have an image, `cat.jpg`, that is being cloned, resized (halved, to be precise), then sent to a random position on the page via jQuery's `.css()` and `.animate()`. Now, when a cat is clicked, I'd like it to generate a new image/element in its place temporarily before removing it. So the order of events would be:

1. Click cat.
2. Cat explodes into 3 smaller kittens.
3. Clicked cat element is removed and a new image temporarily takes its place.
4. Cat replacement image is removed after set amount of time (say, one second).

Here's where I'm at thus far. Everything is up to snuff save for keeping the new kittens within the document boundaries (which I'll solve on my own) and the replacement image.  Here's the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G6XTz/3/), and here's the code:

```
  var explode;
  $('img.cat').click(explode=function() {
      var contW = $(document).width();
      var contH = $(document).height();

      for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
        var source = $(this).position();
        var posNeg = Math.random() < 0.5 ? -1 : 1;
        var newTop = Math.floor(Math.random() * (contH / 2 + (posNeg * $(this).height()))) * posNeg;
        var posNeg = Math.random() < 0.5 ? -1 : 1;
        var newLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * (contW / 2 + (posNeg * $(this).width()))) * posNeg;

        var $kitty = $(this).clone().css({
          width: $(this).width() / 2,
          height: $(this).height() / 2
        });
        $('#container').append($kitty);
        $kitty.css({ top: source.top, left: source.left })
          .animate({ top: newTop+'px', left: newLeft+'px' }, 300)
          .click(explode);
      }

      $(this).remove();
  });
```

I know I have to get the current position of the $kitty (or rather `img.cat`) being clicked on and set the new object to that via CSS, but my implementation is flawed.

```
        var $lion = $('#replacement').clone().css({
          top: newTop,
          left: newLeft,
        });
        $('#container').append($lion);

        <img id="replacement" src="http://images1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130326142633/warriors/images/4/47/Lion.png" />
```

How can I get the lion to show up for only a second when any `img.cat` is clicked, and show up in that cat's exact position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of `$(this).remove()` try to replace the cat with lion

```
var $lion = $('<img id="replacement" src="http://images1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130326142633/warriors/images/4/47/Lion.png" />')
$(this).replaceWith($lion);
setTimeout(function () {
    $lion.remove()
}, 1000)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/eadyv/), [Make sure the image is displayed for 1 sec](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/eadyv/2/)

Comment: That's close, but it's always loading the lion in the center of the screen rather than at the position of whichever cat was clicked. I assume this can be rectified with CSS, right?

Comment: what do you mean by `at the position of whichever cat was clicked`

Comment: @daveycroqet did you mean the top left of the lion should be where the mouse pointer was clicked

Comment: I mean when you click a new kitten that's at some random position, the lion should show up positioned there. Each time you click a new kitten, the lion should be where that kitten was.

Comment: Kind of. I mean the top left of the lion should match the top left of the kitten you're clicking on.